# Wrong Format of Date when Displayed

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a column that has a data that looks like this.

`8/31/2017 11:45:41`

and that format is Date Time

now when Im using the google code `.getValues` and display it in `Logger.log`

this is the output

`Fri Sep 01 02:45:41 GMT+08:00 2017`

My Question is How can I get the value as it is? I dont want to get it as time stamp I want the format like `8/31/2017 11:45:41` or `M/D/YYYY HH:MM:SS` really same as what it displays in sheet.

here is my code.

```
//Convert Timestamp to M/D/YYYY HH:mm:ss
function ConvertToYMDHS(inputFormat){
  var userTimeZone = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getTimeZone();
  return inputFormat ? Utilities.formatDate(inputFormat, "GMT-8:00", "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss") : "";
}
```

`ConvertToYMDHS("Cell of the Column that has a Date");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: @D.Simon That question doesn't tell, how to use `Utilities.formatDate` method.

Comment: Thats true so it has nothing to do with the possible duplicate youve tag to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a modification as follows?

#### From :

```
var val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").getValue();
Logger.log(val)

>>> Thu Aug 31 11:45:41 GMT+09:00 2017
```

#### To :

```
var val = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").getDisplayValue();
Logger.log(val)

>>> 08/31/2017 11:45:41
```

Of course, you can also use `getDisplayValues()` for retrieving values from several cells as 2 dimensiolnal array.

- The detail information of `getDisplayValue()` is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue).
- The detail information of `getDisplayValues()` is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Wow! Thats simple yet so awesome

Comment: Wow your soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo awesome love you men <3

Comment: @paul pagente Thank you. ``getDisplayValue()`` can retrieve the value displayed in the cell.

Comment: Yes TYSM for big help

Comment: Hi Sir TYSM again. #MyHero

Comment: @paul pagente oh, again?

Comment: No Problem Sir. I just cant move on from this topic. You really did a great help. TYSM from the bottom of my left venticel(Heart) hahaha

Comment: @paul pagente I'm glad I could be helpful for you.

Comment: Looking forward to have a more conversation with you because, I checked your profile and I noticed we have in common and that is Google Spcript especially in Google Sheet.

Comment: @paul pagente Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an HO Account?

Comment: @paul pagente Sorry. I don't know about it.

Comment: ahh i see. its ok, looking forward to see you here around again. TY